# Applying Wrapper class to <div>

Tags: css, html

Here is my UI design

```
<div>
    <ul>
         <li>
             <a></a>
         </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to create a menu. 
The text for the anchor will be set on run time and can be of any length but I don't want text to be wrapped. any idea how can I solve this.

Comment: You're creating a menu? Do yourself a favour and use an existing plugin like superfish.

Comment: @sohnee you are right but I not got any working answer for my questions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent text from wrapping using a CSS rule, use the following:

```
ul li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```